# Painting shapes and patterns on the mesh

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, texture-painting

How to paint various shapes on the object with precision and ability for fast adjustment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create object(s) close to the surface of the painted object (UV unwrapped object with a texture).
Add various materials on different parts of the shape object.

[image]

Add Subdivision Surface modifier with 2 or more subdivisions.
Make creases where it is necessary to preserve sharp edges of the shapes.
Add Shrinkwrap modifier with **Target** set to painted object and set mode to **Projection**.

[image]

Select shape object(s) and the painted object as last one, then open Render tab and in Bake settings select **Textures** as bake mode, enable **Selected to Active** and adjust **Distance** to prevent baking to the opposite side of the mesh. Then hit **Bake** button.

[image]

Final result:

[image]