# Painting shapes on the mesh

Tags: texture-painting

Since Texture Paint lacks the option to add simple shapes like ellipses, rectangles, etc. I would like to know if there is any other way to get this done ? I found this: [Painting shapes and patterns on the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31010/painting-shapes-and-patterns-on-the-mesh)
but it doesn't seem to work in 2.93, unless I'm doing something wrong (I'm a Blender newbie).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here just the very basic steps:

1. add plane

[image]

2. add material, name it bake, use these nodes

[image]

3. tap an "new" in image texture and choose the resolution you want to have
4. tap ok
5. add another material by tapping "+"

[image]

6. use these nodes:

[image]

7. add a circle, Tab -> edit mode, press F, Tab -> object mode

[image]

8. choose the material by tapping here [image] from point 5

[image]

9. add a shrinkwrap modifier like this to your circle:

[image]

10. change to cycles

[image]

11. go to bake settings, choose these:

[image]

Select first your circle, then Shift-Select the plane,

then hit bake

Wait a bit.

Now hide the circle or move it away and you will see that your texture is baked on the plane.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks, but does it only work on flat surfaces, like a plane ? I tried doing this on my model, but after I clicked Bake, the whole model went black and the shape kind of disintegrated into pieces and was scattered all over the model.

Comment: nope, should work on model as well. can u provide blend file? or a video how you made it?

Comment: Maybe instead you could describe step by step how to add, let's say a blue square into a yellow subdivided cube. I tried to do it myself, but of course it didn't work for me, the sphere (cube) is still all yellow.

Comment: that's what i did in the answer. Just use the cube instead of a plane. I can only help you if you show me what you did. Either with a blend file or a video.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=QBvso1R0" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QBvso1R0/)

Comment: I wanted to get a blue square shape on the top half of the yellow sphere (subdivided cube).

Comment: This is how the baked texture looks https://imgur.com/PcnrVDv